# ITEM_CLICK handler for ListEvent using Flex 4

Tags: events, flex4

how to set ITEM_CLICK for spark ListEvent in flex 4 mobile project. I have tried like this,.

```
import spark.events.ListEvent;
fileList.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_CLICK,itemDownloadHandler);

private function itemDownloadHandler(event:ListEvent):void
        {
            trace("now in item");
            // creating new FileReference
            file= new FileReference();
            // saving the clicked item to your computer
            // brings out a savedialogue

               file.save(event.itemRenderer.data.file,event.itemRenderer.data.label);

        }
```

this code is working fine in Flex 3, but I don't know how to use this click event in flex 4. I have tried ItemClickEvent also, but I don't know how to use event.itemRenderer in ItemClickevent. kindly anyone suggest me some ideas to solve this problem. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Flex4, there is no `ITEM_CLICK` event on List components anymore. You can add `MOUSE_CLICK` listener inside List's `RENDERER_ADD` and remove the click listener in `RENDERER_REMOVE` handlers. I use this approach to make sure renderer instance can be GCed.
[API: RENDERER_ADD/RENDERER_REMOVE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/SkinnableDataContainer.html#event%3arendererAdd)

For example:

```
fileList.addEventListener(RendererExistenceEvent.RENDERER_ADD , onRendererAdd );
fileList.addEventListener(RendererExistenceEvent.RENDERER_REMOVE , onRendererRemove);

function onRendererAdd(event:RendererExistenceEvent){
event.renderer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onRendererClick );
};

function onRendererRemove(event:RendererExistenceEvent){
event.renderer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , onRendererClick );
};

function onRendererClick(event:MouseEvent){
// your actions here ... 
trace("now in item");
};
```